# Вывод данных из нескольких несвязанных таблиц yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как можно реализовать вывод данных из нескольких несвязанных таблиц в yii2? C одной таблицей просто создавал модель, с помощью Gii, затем добавлял crud и выводил на форму.

Comment: А в чем смысл выводить вместе 2 несвязанные таблицы одним запросом? Тут или нужно 2 запроса, или нужно чтобы таблицы были связанные.

Comment: @lyhoshva есть база, в которой есть куча таблиц без внешних ключей. данные в бд постоянно обновляются. Задача: выцеплять данные из нескольких таблиц(каждый день) и сохранять их в другую базу, чтобы они не были подвержены изменениям.

Comment: Если таблицы не связаны логически то нужно делать через несколько запросов. Если просто нету внешних ключей то просто делать связи - для них внешние ключи как таковые не нужны (нужно просто указать по какому полю связать таблицы)